# why Ubuntu-4.15.0-76.86 which is based on 4.15.18 have some extra git commits from 5.0

Tags: kernel, git

Previously, I thought Ubuntu-4.15.0-76.86  is based on 4.15.18
[image]

However, I just found it has some commits from kernel. For example ,ef61eb43ada6c1d6b94668f0f514e4c268093ff3 is a commit from linux 5.0
In ubuntu source code directory, the output of

```
git show ef61eb43ada6c1d6b94668f0f514e4c268093ff3
```

is totally the same as in mainline kernel.
The result of

```
git describe ef61eb43ada6c1d6b94668f0f514e4c268093ff3
```

is also v5.0-12878-gef61eb43ada6.
So Ubuntu-4.15.0-76.86 also forks from 5.0 and other kernel versions, not only from 4.15.18? They all exists in the source code directory as a branch?

Thanks

Comment: Open-source projects can have commits backported from later versions. This case could have been just an extremely lucky one, which required no backporting!

Comment: Ubuntu back-ports security patches/fixes from later kernels to supported kernels.  The 4.15 kernel is used by Ubuntu 18.04 LTS so it'll thus have security fixes back-ported to it during it's supported life (this applies to other supported kernels, however generally not to new features - only security patches).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu back-ports security patches/fixes from later kernels to supported kernels.

The 4.15 kernel is used by Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (plus 16.04 LTS with HWE enabled etc) so it'll thus have security fixes back-ported to it during it's supported life.  This applies to other supported kernels, however generally not to new features - only security fixes/patches.

Comment: But the patch/fix what the ubuntu really applies is not the patch from later kernel? For example, ef61eb43ada6c1d6b94668f0f514e4c268093ff3 is a patch in 5.0. But there is a commit 999238803d9b54e49e16e18963205155a150622e which ubuntu really use it to fix. And it's commit message has "upstream: ef61eb43ada6c1d6b94668f0f514e4c268093ff3". So what's the meaning of having ef61eb43ada6c1d6b94668f0f514e4c268093ff3 in ubuntu's git repository? As ubuntu has its own patch. Thanks.

Comment: The 4.15 kernel code will of course be different to the 5.0 kernel, thus why patches need to be back-ported, which may require a change to make it work for 4.15 as intended and not create regressions due to differences in the 4.15 kernel code (when compared to 5.0 or later kernel the patches were written for). Back-porting is more than just applying code without change, it's reviewing it to see if change(s) are required and adjusting for the older kernel, then testing first in PPA or first testing, to -proposed, before eventual SRU/*stable release update* and getting to production systems.

Comment: So  every time ubuntu is patched a bug, ubuntu will add a git commit which is the patch for the bug in the mainline kernel?

Comment: why it need to add a total version in the repository if we want to backport a patch/fix?